# Using Local Notification with CoreData as a monthly reminder

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uilocalnotification

I have a app that is keeping track of a list of objects. I would like each object in the list to have a reminder set for them when the object is created. I would also like to give the user the ability to go back into the object and either change the reminder or remove it all together. My question is what piece of data do I need to save in order to have those abilities? I'm using CoreData and I'm not sure what I need to save for each reminder for each object.

SO for example maybe on object has a reminder every 2 weeks, and another object has a reminder every 30 days. What piece of data do I need to save in that entity in CoreData?

Thanks for the help as always!

Comment: You can ask the app for its local notifications and modify them, the question isn't really clear...

Comment: OK I'll rework the quesiton

Comment: Wain, does the question make more sense now?

Answer (score 2):

- Save object in database
- Schedule `UILocalNotification` for it with the `repeat interval` and assign the object unique id in the `userInfo` of  `UILocalNotification`.
- When your object is modified, iterate through all the scheduled notification, get the one that has been modified, update the object, cancel previous notification and schedule new one for it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at 2 things:

1. A unique I'd so you can link to object and its notification
2. A reminder days duration number

You could also store the enabled state either on each object or globally (perhaps in user defaults).

Now, when something changes, you can iterate through the local notifications registered with the app and update the appropriate one.